# Libgdx Drawing a triangle cannot resolve method "render "

Tags: libgdx, android

I want to draw a triangle. I found a lot of [code such as this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/My-First-Triangle-%28Example%29).

I thiknk the code I found is old; if I use

```
mesh.render(GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

Then the compiler cannot resolve method.

How can I draw a triangle or solve this problem?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Gamedev.SE! We need to see more of your code. That error is so generic, that none can help you with that information. Edit your question and give more information about your problem. Maybe someone can help you then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ShapeRenderer http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html.

Note that it's pretty slow and you'd better just use triangle sprite for that.